# Format money number_format PHP

Tags: php

C:\xampp\htdocs\ksucatalog\application\helpers\nokencode_helper.php
Line: 118
Function: number_format

Message: number_format(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($num) of type float is deprecated

code:

```
if (!function_exists('money')) {
    function money($str)
    {
        return number_format($str, 2, '.', ',');
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you pass null as content of $str. Can you show us how you call the function?

Comment: how are you calling your function `money` and what is the value you are passing into it